# Wrap label around UIbutton

Tags: ios, ios-autolayout

I'm trying to create a view like below using storyboard in Xcode. 
[image]

For this, I've added a button and a label with constraints but this is the result I get. The text doesn't start below the checkbox. One way to achieve this would be to create 2 labels and add the strings that start after `this` string to 2 label and place it under the first label.

[image]

Is there any better way to do this? Also, when you click on Read more the text can expand as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the leading of the button and the label the same ( button above label ) and insert some empty characters at the beginning of the label text

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do a way. Take the button and the label in a view

then sub divide the view into two views, left one holds the button and right one holds the label. make a gap between left and right

button's constraint will be leading , top and trailing to zero and height as your wish

label's constraint will be leading , top, trailing and bottom.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by using a `UITextView` and setting an **ExclusionPath**.

The **ExclusionPath** (or paths) defines an area within the text view's `textContainer` around which the text should wrap.

If you disable scrolling, selection and editing of the `UITextView` it will behave just like a `UILabel` but will also give you the benefit of **ExclusionPath**

Here is a simple example - lots of hard-coded values, so you'd probably want to make it a custom class - but this should get you on your way:

```
class TextViewLabel: UITextView {

    override init(frame: CGRect, textContainer: NSTextContainer?) {
        super.init(frame: frame, textContainer: textContainer)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() -> Void {
        isScrollEnabled = false
        isEditable = false
        isSelectable = false
        textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
        textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0
    }

}

class ExclusionViewController: UIViewController {

    let checkBox: UIButton = {
        let v = UIButton()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return v
    }()

    let theTextViewLabel: TextViewLabel = {
        let v = TextViewLabel()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = .yellow
        v.text = "I agree to receive information about this application and all the updates related to this..."
        v.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20.0)
        return v
    }()

    var isChecked: Bool = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(theTextViewLabel)
        theTextViewLabel.addSubview(checkBox)

        let cbWidth = CGFloat(20)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            theTextViewLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 100.0),
            theTextViewLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            theTextViewLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 240.0),

            checkBox.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theTextViewLabel.topAnchor, constant: 2.0),
            checkBox.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theTextViewLabel.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            checkBox.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: cbWidth),
            checkBox.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: cbWidth),

            ])

        theTextViewLabel.textContainer.exclusionPaths = [
            UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: cbWidth + 8.0, height: cbWidth))
        ]

        updateCheckboxImage()

        checkBox.addTarget(self, action: #selector(checkBoxTapped), for: .touchUpInside)

    }

    func updateCheckboxImage() -> Void {
        if isChecked {
            checkBox.setImage(UIImage(named: "SmallChecked"), for: .normal)
        } else {
            checkBox.setImage(UIImage(named: "SmallUnChecked"), for: .normal)
        }
    }

    @objc func checkBoxTapped() -> Void {
        isChecked = !isChecked
        updateCheckboxImage()
    }

}
```

Result:

[image]

(I used these two images for the checkBox):

[image] [image]